# "Add to Campaign" button at Contact Details Page

Tags: list, list-view, campaign

I'm trying to customize my contact layout and our communications department wants to have "Add to Campaign" button right at Contact Details Page Layout. I tried to add standard "Add to Campaign" button, but it doesn't seem to be available in page layout editor, and when I add "New Campaign" button, it never shows up.

Ideally I want to have a popup window with Campaign selection. Same window you have in List View when you click "Add to Campaign" button.

Comment: classic or lightning?

Comment: @cropredy Lightning! Sorry I always forget.

Comment: It seems like I need to create Lightning Component to create a Button at Contact Details Page Layout. And then to write some code. I'm coming closer to understanding but it seems so complicated.

Comment: you could use a quick action

Comment: @cropredy hm... can you tell me more about quick actions? or give me a link to some place I can learn more?

Comment: I just can't see how I can use quick action to "add user to a campaign"

Comment: quick action to a Visualforce page/controller would be one approach